# How do I specify which provisioning profile is used for app store deployment?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I am adding push notifications to an app that I distribute to my team via TestFlight. I've created both a development and distribution certificate for APNS, and I re-issued my development and distribution provisioning profiles with the additional `aps-environment` entitlement.

When I archive my app, I can choose the "Export" option.

- If I choose "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment", Xcode signs the app using my distribution provisioning profile.
- If I choose "Save for Development Deployment", Xcode signs the app using my development provisioning profile.
- If I choose "Save for iOS App Store Deployment" **OR** click on the "Upload to App Store..." button, Xcode signs the app with the `XC: *` wildcard provisioning profile which does not include the `aps-environment` entitlement.

If I delete the `XC: *` provisioning profile from the developer console and try over again, I get an error when attempting upload to the app store:

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.ionicframework.pro305288' is not available. Please enter a different string.

If I look at my Organizer and choose to validate one of my earlier releases, the `XC: *` profile re-appears in my developer console and I'm back to square 1.

If I look at the version history of the app, all previous releases were signed with the `XC: *` profile. I figured that the provisioning profile might be tied to the app ID, so I created a completely new app ID with all new certificates and provisioning profiles, but I had the same problem.

It doesn't matter if I manually specify the provisioning profile in the build settings either. Xcode always tries to use the same stupid wildcard provisioning profile for app store builds.

**Main Question**: How do I tell Xcode to sign my app with the correct provisioning profile when uploading to the app store?

**Bonus Question**: How can I tell which provisioning profile is used to sign my app when I run it directly on a device attached to my computer via USB?

---

**EDIT**

As requested, this is the code signing section of my build settings for my target.

[image: Code Signing]

The provisioning profile is currently set to "Automatic" but my issue persists if I change the selection to either my development or distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: Can you show your Code Signing section of your Build Settings for your project?

Comment: Also make sure you are selecting the target in the left when you are looking at the Build Settings.

Comment: Your release code signing identity should be set to iOS Distribution.  You can't submit to the app store with a developer signed app.

Comment: No matter what code signing identity or provisioning profile I select in the build settings, whenever I click "Upload to App Store..." it always lists `XC: *` as the provisioning profile.